# how to add value of type INT into list using python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

A loop produces interger values and I want to store them into a list.

Ex: on 1st iteration I'll get 510, 510 should be stored or added into list. on 2nd iteration I'll get 1780, 1780 should be stored in to list as a integer.

on each iteration ill get the values & it should get stored into list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an empty list like so

```
list_example = []
```

In this case, the "name" of the list is called `list_example`. Since it is an instance of a list, you may use methods (functions) that pertain to things you would like to do with lists. For example, the function `append` may be of use to you. The following code

```
list_example.append(510)
```

"appends" the number 510 to the end of the list.

```
>>> print(list_example)
[510]
```

Other list functions are available in docs, and I would spend some time on an introductory python course or book so you can be familiar with basic python.